# Storing Firebase accessToken in Pinia store - Vue3

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, pinia

I'm fairly new to Vue and it's my first time using Pinia. I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/@charliepython/pinia-firebase-v9-and-axios-with-vue-3-composition-6261626da931) to set up Firebase, Pinia and Axios. The app I'm building uses FirebaseUI to sign a user in, via an email link - this all happens in the LoginPage component below:

(Please ignore all incorrectly types variables/functions - I'm just trying to get this working in the first place)

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { EmailAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "firebaseui";
import { auth as firebaseAuth } from "../firebase/config";
import { useUserStore } from "../stores/user"

onMounted(async () => {
  const uiConfig: auth.Config = {
    signInSuccessUrl: "/",
    signInOptions: [
      {
        provider: EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        signInMethod: EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
        forceSameDevice: true,
      },
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
        const store = useUserStore();
        store.user = authResult;
        return true;
      },
    },
  };
  const ui = new auth.AuthUI(firebaseAuth);
  ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
});
</script>
<template>
  <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
</template>
```

When the user successfully signs in, the app updates the Pinia store user object, with the [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult) return object from the `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` function. When debugger, I can see that the object being stored looks like the following:

```
{
    additionalUserInfo: {...}
    operationType: "signIn"
    user: {
        accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N..."
        auth: {...}
        displayName: null
        ...
    }
}
```

I.e. the `accessToken` is being stored. The user store is below:

```html
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore("userStore", {
  state: () => ({
    user: null as any
  }),
  getters: {
    getUser(state) {
      return state.user
    }
  }
})
```

In the app I have set up an axios interceptor, that appends the `accessToken` to any Axios request made by the app:

```html
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore();
  
  if (userStore) {
    debugger;
    // accessToken is undefined
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + userStore.user.user.accessToken;
  }
  return config;
});
```

When attempting the retrieve the `accessToken` from the user store at this point, it's gone. Most (if not all) of the other properties from the user object still exist, but not the access token, therefore I'm pretty sure I'm using the store correctly:

```
{
    additionalUserInfo: {...}
    credential: null
    operationType: "signIn"
    user: {
        // accessToken is gone
        apiKey: "..."
        appName: "[DEFAULT]"
        email: "..."
        emailVerified: true
        ....
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain where I'm going wrong with this, and why the `accessToken` is being removed from the store? It looks to me as though I'm using the Pinia store correctly, and I'm pretty sure that the interceptor is also correct. However it's likely that I'm going about storing the access token in the wrong way. I'd appreciate any help/advice about how to setup Firebase authentication correctly with Vue.

*Edited to include value of the user store when debugging inside the interceptor.*

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem, it contains unrelated parts. No explanation exists why one property would be undefined, unless you set it explicitly. If  `user` is null, `user.accessToken` will throw an error. If it's equal to `authResult`, and there is `accessToken`, `user.accessToken` will be defined.  `store.user = authResult` - this is a mistake. Store state shouldn't be modified directly, only in actions. Then this can be visible in dev tools. "When debugger, I can see" - which debugger? I believe the problem is not reproducible at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @EstusFlask - I've only added sections of code that are applicable to the issue. No where else in my application am I updating the user pinia store, only in the sections above. I believe that I am able to directly modify the state from inside a component - https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#accessing-the-state (however strange that seems). As you say, 'if it's equal to authResult, and there is accessToken, user.accessToken will be defined' - I completely agree, and yet when I access the object, it's undefined, yet the user name, email etc. still exist.

Comment: You can modify a state outside but you shouldn't, it's a bad practice because it cannot be tracked to a specific action. It's not enforced in Pinia yet but this practice is inherited from Vuex. Please, provide a way to reproduce it. Currently the only explanation is that it wasn't properly debugged, it's unknown how exactly this was done. Also use Pinia devtools where possible

Answer (score 0):

It looks like accessToken might be in userStore.user.user.accessToken?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the value `userStore.user.user`. `accessToken` no long exists on the object

Answer (score 0):

Im just finishing the same battle that you are in... IMO there are many ways that this setup can be configured... This is similar to why you might use callbacks in one place, and async await in another it depends on your project structure.

Heres a simple example that might help you clarify it.

**first**
create a firebase file to hold the config put this where ever your organization habits tells you to put it. Just remember so we can use it later.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//initialize firebase auth
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

**Second - userStore**

The user store does the legwork. We will use the actions when we want to interact with userauth from our ui.

```
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

import { auth } from "../firebase"; // the file we made above

import router from "../router";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("userStore", {
  state: () => ({
    userData: null,
    loadingUser: false,
    loadingSession: false,
  }),
  actions: {
    async registerUser(email, password) {
      this.loadingUser = true;
      try {
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email,
          password
        );
        this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
        router.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        this.loadingUser = false;
      }
    },
    async loginUser(email, password) {
      this.loadingUser = true;
      try {
        const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email,
          password
        );
        this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
        router.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        this.loadingUser = false;
      }
    },
    async logOutUser() {
      try {
        await signOut(auth);
        this.userData = null;
        router.push("/login");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    currentUser() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const unsuscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
          auth,
          (user) => {
            if (user) {
              this.userData = { email: user.email, password: user.password };
            } else {
              this.userData = null;
            }
            resolve(user);
          },
          (e) => reject(e)
        );
        unsuscribe();
      });
    },
  },
});
```

*** step3 setup the login / reg components in vue. ***

```
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" v-model="email" required />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" v-model="password" required />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useUserStore } from "../stores/user";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        await this.userStore.loginUser(this.email, this.password);  // 
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },

// because of below setup you can access this.userStore() singleton 

  setup() {  
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    return {
      userStore,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

***register is going to be simailar***

```
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="register">
      <label>
        Email:

        <input type="email" v-model="email" required />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" v-model="password" required />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { useUserStore } from "../stores/user";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async register() {
      try {
        await this.userStore.registerUser(this.email, this.password);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    return {
      userStore,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

now whenever you want to access the user it is in userStore.userData

if you dont have the userStore up yet just use the useUserStore() method and access it the same way you do from the setup in login / register view